# Change String.Substring

Tags: c#, .net

```
string url = "www.google.com/?filter=xpto";
string domain = url.Contains('?')
                ? url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf('?'));
                : url;
```

Is there a simpler way to do this w/o having to override Substring method?

Comment: You can't override `Substring`. `String` is sealed.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the term "override"... Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Wat is the difficult part?

Comment: `domain = new Uri("http://" + url).Host;`

Comment: i'm really impressed by the great detailed answers to such simple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write own extension method:

```
public static string GetDomain(this string url)
{
      return url.Contains('?')
                ? url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf('?'));
                : url;
}
```

Usage:

```
string domain = url.GetDomain();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also not use string methods if you work with [`Uri`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx). Since your uri is somewhat malformed(f.e. it doesn't contain the protocol) it's a little bit more difficult to extract the domain:

```
string url = "www.google.com/?filter=xpto";
if (!url.Contains("://")) url = "http://" + url;  // presume HTTP
string domain = url;
string host = url;
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
{
    domain = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority); // http://www.google.com
    host = uri.Host; // www.google.com, without protocol or port
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead ?

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/?filter=xpto");
var domain = url.Host;
Console.WriteLine(domain);
```